# Showing that $\lim_{x\to3} x^2 = 9$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am showing that $\lim_{x\to3} x^2 = 9$. And from a book, the first part of proving the limit (the preliminary analysis where we make a guess - not the second part where you actually prove the correctness of this guess) goes like this
[image]
I tried to do it myself before reading the answer and tried to do
[image]
So why doesn't the author choose $\delta = \epsilon / (x-3)$? There is obviously a reason and I assume my way is wrong.

Comment: You want to find a fixed number $\delta$. You suggest $\delta = \epsilon/(x-3)$. If $\delta$ is fixed, then so is $x$ in there. So, what's that fixed $x$ then?

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is to notice that your $\delta$ is not allowed to depend on $x$. Indeed by definition we have $$\forall \varepsilon>0 \; \exists \delta>0 \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R} : |x-3|< \delta \Rightarrow |(x^2 - 9)| < \varepsilon$$.

Read this as you first pick any epsilon and then choose a nice delta. But the trick is that the same delta has to work for all $x$.